# Importing pyglet.resource takes an inordinate amount of time in large directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyglet

Importing [`pyglet.resource`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.resource-module.html) takes a very long time when run from a directory with a large directory tree structure. It happens with the simple one-liner: `import pyglet.resource`, which in a large enough directory (say, my home directory) will simply cause the interpreter to hang.

If the import is interrupted with <kbd>C-c</kbd>, the following traceback is printed, suggesting that the entire directory tree is being traversed:

```
>>> import pyglet.resource
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/__init__.py", line 306, in __getattr__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/resource.py", line 680, in <module>
    _default_loader = _DefaultLoader()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/resource.py", line 291, in __init__
    self.reindex()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/resource.py", line 335, in reindex
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 284, in walk
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

<sup>(With a variable number of `walk` calls, depending on how long the script is left running)</sup>

This is surprising since importing pyglet.resource really shouldn't need to traverse the script's directory anyway. What causes this, and can it be fixed or worked-around?

---

Version info: Python 2.7, Pyglet 1.1.4, Ubuntu 12.04

This problem appears to have been described in [this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/pyglet-users/83pe-B1J2EQ/discussion) pyglet-users discussion, where it was incorrectly attributed to constructing a `pyglet.resource.FileLocation` object. However, the issue actually occurs during the implied import in a script like

```
import pyglet

...

pyglet.resource.FileLocation(...)  # pyglet.resource is imported here;
                                   # FileLocation is not the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this problem was reported as [issue #367](https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/issues/detail?id=367) in Pyglet; it was fixed in [revision  9664bc47446c](https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/detail?r=9664bc47446c2bac27248d32e225879bf05833ae&path=/pyglet/resource.py) (which was after release 1.1.4).